# Criar lista com a soma dos números consecutivos iguais

Tags: python, lista

Essa é a minha estrutura, mas o `if`, `elif` e até o `else` (embora não estejam no código), não estão funcionando. O código está imprimindo várias linhas como se fossem `if`'s separados e a função tem que somar números consecutivos iguais.

Exemplo: Se for inserido `[1,2,2,2,3,4,4]`, o programa tem que retornar `[1,6,3,8]`.

```
lista  = []
lista1 = []

while len(lista) + 1 < 8:
 lista.append(int(input("Digite o valor: ")))

print(lista)

for i in range(1, len(lista)):

    if lista[i - 1] == lista[i] and lista[i] == lista[i + 1]:

        lista1.append(lista[i - 1] + lista[i] + lista[i + 1])

    elif lista[i - 1] == lista[i]:

        lista1.append(lista[i - 1] + lista[i])

    elif lista[i - 1] != lista[i]: 

        lista1.append(lista[i])
        print(lista[0], lista1)

print(lista1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) da biblioteca padrão [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#module-itertools), veja só:

```
from itertools import groupby

entrada = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4]

saida = [sum(i) for _, i in groupby(entrada)]

print(saida)
```

Saída:

```
[1, 6, 3, 8]
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LongParchedBlockchain)

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4]

def func(lista):
    resultado = []
    soma = lista[0]
    for i in range(1, len(lista)):
        if lista[i] == lista[i-1]:
            soma += lista[i]
            if i == len(lista)-1:
                resultado += [soma]
        else:
            resultado += [soma]
            soma = lista[i]
    return resultado

func(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Um erro está no primeiro `if`. Como você faz o `for i in range(1, len(lista))`, o que acontece quando `i` chega em `len(lista) - 1`?

Por exemplo, para a lista `[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4 ]`, que tem 7 elementos, os índices válidos são de 0 a 6. Quando `i` chega em 6, você faz no primeiro `if`:

```
if lista[i - 1] == lista[i] and lista[i] == lista[i + 1]:
```

Quando você faz `lista[i + 1]`, está tentando acessar o índice 7, que não existe na lista, e ocorre um [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError). E o código está imprimindo várias linhas porque você colocou um `print` no último `elif`, então sempre que cair ali vai imprimir algo.

Mas o problema principal é o algoritmo em si. O primeiro `if` verifica se o elemento é igual ao anterior e ao próximo, e já insere a soma dos 3 na lista de resultados. Mas e se tiver 4 (ou mais) números consecutivos iguais?  Você só deveria inserir na lista de resultados quando o número mudasse (além de atualizar a soma enquanto o número não muda). Uma alternativa é fazer assim:

```
def somar_consecutivos(lista):
    sum = ant = lista[0]
    res = []
    for i in range(1, len(lista)):
        n = lista[i]
        if n == ant:
            sum += n
        else:
            res.append(sum)
            sum = n
        ant = n
    res.append(sum)
    return res

print(somar_consecutivos([1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 3, 1])) # [1, 12, 0, 4, 6, 1]
print(somar_consecutivos([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 3, 3])) # [30, 0, 2, 6]
print(somar_consecutivos([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])) # [1, 6, 3, 8]
print(somar_consecutivos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Eu começo com o primeiro elemento da lista, e depois, para os demais elementos, eu sempre verifico se ele é igual ao anterior. Se for, eu atualizo a soma, e se não for (ou seja, o número mudou), aí sim eu adiciono a soma acumulada até então na lista de resultados.